# Assign viewbag value to model items causes an error in mvc4

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am trying to pass an value from my view to my controller:

```
 public ActionResult Create(int id)
        {
            ViewBag.ConferenceRegesterId = id;

            return View();
        }
```

As you can see in `create` action i save my id in `viewbag` .i need this id in post back so i have this code for postback :

```
  [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Creat(MvcConference.Models.Details1 ObjDetails)
        {

            dbcontext.Details1.Add(ObjDetails);
            dbcontext.SaveChanges();
            List<MvcConference.Models.Details1> lstuser = dbcontext.Details1.ToList();
            return View("Index");

        }
```

I use this code to assign my viewbag value to my model item in my `create` view

```
            @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.ConferenceRegesterId=ViewBag.ConferenceRegesterId)
```

but finally after executing i got this error :

```
Description: An error occurred during the compilation of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific error details and modify your source code appropriately. 

Compiler Error Message: CS1963: An expression tree may not contain a dynamic operation
```

I will be apprciate for any help

Best regards

Comment: `model => model.ConferenceRegesterId=ViewBag.conference=ViewBag.ConferenceRegesterId)` Two assignements (with = sign) are happening in this piece of code. If the value you're trying to access is part of the model then better access the model's property value during `POST`. WHy would you assign it through a viewbag?

Comment: It was typing error sorry i edited it ,because this is the FK in another table

Comment: You can't just assign the value for a model's property through a view like the way you're currently doing.

Comment: Why are you trying to pass a value back to the controller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't just assign the value for a model's property in a view (through viewbag) like the way you're currently doing, because you're not creating an instance of the class. Please note that only value bound to the input elements are posted back to the controller.

Slightly change the way your program currently behaves. Your `create` action in the controller will crate an instance for your viewmodel and initialize the required members (`ConferenceRegesterId`). This model will be strongly bound to the `create` view.

```
 public ActionResult Create(int id)
 {
     MvcConference.Models.Details1 viewmodel = new MvcConference.Models.Details1(); 
     viewmodel.ConferenceRegesterId  = id;
     return View(viewmodel);
 }
```

Your `create` view

```
@model MvcConference.Models.Details1
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
  ......

  @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.ConferenceRegesterId)
}
```

Now your `ObjDetails` in `POST` action can access the value of `ConferenceRegesterId` you passed through the hiddenfield input element.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need any model. That's simple problem. When you use a ViewBag you must convert that object to static object on your Razor View.

Like that;

```
@{ 
   string varName = ViewBag.varName;
}
```

And you will not see again that;

```
Compiler Error Message: CS1963: An expression tree may not contain a dynamic operation
```